# Designing HTML from beginning compatible to all browsers of all devices?

Tags: html

we are developing new website and 
i know little bit about HTML
so can suggest any solid open-source 
tools for good HTML design.

Answer (score 2):

Check about boilerplates in http://www.initializr.com/

It is a good way to start a project and it covers alot about browsers compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not a place to be asking for recommendations but you should look at [responsive CSS frameworks](http://designshack.net/articles/css/which-is-right-for-me-22-responsive-css-frameworks-and-boilerplates-explained/) as a good starting point. If you're unfamiliar with CSS then it is something you *must* learn in order to create responsive designs.